# jquery focus to table

Tags: jquery

I want to bring focus to first row in a table when a page loads.I am using this for navigation
in a table using key board.How do i bring focus and some times this keyboard navigation is also not working 
http://jsfiddle.net/hKZqS/8/ When using key board this is removing zebra stripes

Answer (score 1):

Try the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTable tbody tr").first().addClass("ui-selected");
});

// Do the clever keypress stuff
$(document).keyup( function(e)
{
    switch(e.which)
    {
        // user presses the "a" key
        case 38:
            if(!e.ctrlKey) {
                var selected = $("tr.ui-selected").first();
                if (selected.prev().html() != null) {
                    selected.prev().addClass("ui-selected");
                    selected.removeClass("ui-selected");
                }
            }
            break;    
        // user presses the "s" key
        case 40:  
            if(!e.ctrlKey) {
                var selected = $("tr.ui-selected").first();
                if (selected.next().html() != null) {
                    selected.next().addClass("ui-selected");
                    selected.removeClass("ui-selected");
                }
            }
            break;
    }
});
```

I tested it out and it seems to be working on a modified version of your jsFiddle: [See Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hKZqS/14/)

Comment: @FarlingOpptredon:When i use this code with jquery table sorter it is not working[http://tablesorter.com/docs/]

Comment: Could you possibly share a sample of where you're applying it to the jQuery table sorter? Remember, this sample I gave looks for a table with the ID "mytable", as per your original example. A better solution would obviously to specify a specific CSS class, instead on an ID. The rest is also dependent on CSS classes.

Comment: FarligOpptreden :Pls see that tablesorter link.I am using id only.How css classes.Can u modify u r eg'I did n't specify selectme class.Is that a problem.

Comment: I see the table sorter sample you sent me has a differing structure to what I sent you. All that's required is a different initial selector. I updated my code sample to reflect it.