# zebra stripes over riding my highlighting color

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [zebra stripes over riding my highlighting color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177675/zebra-stripes-over-riding-my-highlighting-color)

I am using this code to navigate through keyboard in table grid.In my code i have not added this zebra stripes coding.If i add this zebra stripes is overriding my highlighting.
eg:first row dark color and second row white color.I can see highlight through keyboard in first row but i can see in second row.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/hKZqS/15/]
```

This coding for zebra stripes

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra']} );
```

I have an alternate solution is using border but how do i apply it here in my css.

Comment: why to post a question twice?

Comment: duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177675/

Comment: Hey, that's my jsFiddle from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167333/jquery-focus-to-table/5167670#5167670 Is this the same person who posted yesterday's question as well?

Comment: Please stop posting duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the rules that set the highlight color to be stronger than the zebra colors. For example:

```
tr.ui-selecting { background: #eee; }
tr.ui-selected { background: #dde; }

.odd {background-color: #ffd;}
.even {background-color: #dff;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hKZqS/16/

Other options are using `.ui-selected,.ui-selected.even,.ui-selected.odd`, or an `!important` rule if you're having a bad day.

See also: [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: while i press key up and own it is not moving to next row but moving like this 5,10,15,20 record

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering your question just builds on my answer from yesterday's question (which I got no rep for >:x), I updated my jsFiddle to use the border for highlighting as well. Maybe try something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/hKZqS/17/). Just remember to set the border on the other classes to "none" and add in a padding or margin so the rows don't "jump".